# Express.js - Listen for shutdown

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Node.js app that uses Express. In that app, I have a block that looks like this:

```
const app = require('./app');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const server = app.listen(port);

server.on('listening', () =>
  console.log(`Application launched on ${app.get('host')}:${port}`)
);
```

This successfully works. It successfully prints the message when the `listening` event is fired. My question is, is there any event I can listen for, for when my server is stopped / shutting down? Or when the server stops listening?

I would like to do some cleanup in this scenario.

Comment: Not sure why you're using backticks in your `console.log` entry. That seems like a mistake.

Comment: Also do you mean the [`exit` event](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit)?

Comment: @tadman The backticks are es6 template strings.

Comment: @Ad.Infinitum Learn something new every day. Thanks!

Comment: sorry for going off-topic, but this is the first time I see someone with a reputation of 268 and 10 gold badges :P

Comment: it depends what kind of clean up, normally you would want to track those things on a higher level. If you are using some process launching mechanism, be it `upstart` or some `node`-specific `pm2` or `forever` you can make sure that the process restarts on crash, or in case of `upstart` perform a clean up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could listen to node's process events for shutdown

```js
// listen for TERM signal .e.g. kill
process.on ('SIGTERM', doSomething);

// listen for INT signal e.g. Ctrl-C
process.on ('SIGINT', doSomething); 

//or even exit event 

process.on('exit',doSomething);
```

Comment: you might want to add what is the difference between those events

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to trap this with [`exit`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit):

```
process.on('exit', function() {
  console.log('Process terminating.')
});
```

As pointed out in the documentation you cannot defer anything, this is a one shot deal.

Comment: where does `process` come from?

Comment: It should be a global that always exists within Node.

Comment: do I need to add process.exit(1) inside the function?

Comment: @O.o This is the exit handler, so that's already been called. This is just an opportunity to do some housekeeping before it terminates. You're not responsible for effecting the termination itself.

Comment: Btw, when I worked with React.JS before, I sometimes felt that console.log took some time, and if so, is there any chance to not being shown the `process terminating`?

Comment: That's usually the case of an exit being initiated, but something's still "running" in an async sense. You may have an outstanding promise, timer, or interval that hasn't yet tripped.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use promises along the following lines to make everything nice and synchronous:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
(async () => {
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world')
})
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server started')
    // If you wanted to test this code, you could close it here.
    // this.close()
  })
  server.on('close', resolve)
})
console.log('After listen')
})()
```

Related: [How to synchronously wait for express.js HTTP server to close after a listen call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70479671/how-to-synchronously-wait-for-express-js-http-server-to-close-after-a-listen-cal)