# How to synchronously wait for express.js HTTP server to close after a listen call?

Tags: express

In order to automate testing of my Express.js, I want to make sure that the tests have finished running when each test decides the results.

Consider this simplified model of that situation:

main.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world')
})
const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  // I would run tests here, which is the 'listen' event.
  console.log('Server started')
  // After the tests, I will close the server from here.
  this.close()
})
// I want to make sure that this runs only after the asserts were done,
// otherwise the test would miss possible failures.
console.log('After listen')
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Running `main` produces:

```
After listen
Server started
```

because the server must be asynchronously starting to listen to connections, so `After listen` runs first. But I want instead to have:

```
Server started
After listen
```

I know about the `'close'` event which would allow me to write:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world')
})
const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  // I would run tests here, which is the 'listen' event.
  console.log('Server started')
  // After the tests, I will close the server from here.
  this.close()
})
server.on('close', () => {
  console.log('After listen')
})
```

but then this just shifts the problem further out to the test infrastructure, which has to make sure that it is able to wait for the `After listen` to happen. Yes, in Mocha this is possible with `done()`, but it would be better to have something simpler more test-system agnostic.

Tested on Node.js 14.15.0.

Related:

- [Express.js - Listen for shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943530/express-js-listen-for-shutdown)
- [What's the best way to test express.js API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63762896/whats-the-best-way-to-test-express-js-api)
- [Wait for the server to listen before running tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254017/wait-for-the-server-to-listen-before-running-tests)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've studied promises a bit more as I should have done earlier, and this is satisfactory approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
(async () => {
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world')
})
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    // I would run tests here, which is the 'listen' event.
    console.log('Server started')
    // After the tests, I will close the server from here.
    this.close()
    resolve()
  })
})
console.log('After listen')
})()
```

This is basically the same general pattern that you can use to synchronize any other asynchronous callback function in JavaScript, e.g. for HTTP requests: [Synchronous request in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048504/synchronous-request-in-node-js/53338670#53338670)

Here I illustrate a fuller test setup which also makes the HTTP requests and asserts things: [What's the best way to test express.js API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63762896/whats-the-best-way-to-test-express-js-api/70479940#70479940)